# How to attach the database to tree view as data source?

Tags: c#, database, treeview

I want to load the treeview with data of single column of self referencing table from a SQL Server database. I want to show treeview as hierarchical manner like parent and child based on self reference to `slno` of the table.

My table looks like this

```
       slno     Ac_nm        Ac_acgrpPrnt
      =====================================
        1         A              0
        2         B              0
        3         c              0
        4         D              0
        5         E              1
        6         F              1
        7         G              3
```

here `A,B,C,D` are parent nodes and `Ac_acgrpPrnt` are `0, E, F` are 1 it indicate children of `A`, `G` is 3 it indicates child of `C`, so these is the hierarchy I want to show in form load in my application, I don't have any idea for do this?

Comment: sory AbZy,i dont have any idea how attach these selfreference table to my treeview directly/

Comment: What is your UI technology?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest way would be to first use Entity Framework to create a Self Referential mapping to the table. This will give you a class  like

```
class Foo
{
     public ObservableCollection<Foo> Children { get; set; }
     {...}
}
```

Then its just a case of binding to a collection of the root nodes in the xaml. Creating a Hierarchial DataTemplate to tell WPF what property is used to find Children and lazy loading will take case of the rest.

However you might find some performance issues here...